# Why XSL:VARIABLE Node don´t appear in my XML File?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the next code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/2" xmlns:ecc="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/2" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"  indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Addenda">
      <xsl:element name="requestForPayment">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">SimpleInvoiceType</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="contentVersion">1.3.1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="documentStructureVersion">AMC7.1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="documentStatus">ORIGINAL</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DeliveryDate">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(//DocDate, ' ', ''),1,10)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="requestForPaymentIdentification">
          <xsl:element name="entityType">
            <xsl:call-template name="Tpos_Documento"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="uniqueCreatorIdentification">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(//Serial/Name,//Serial/Folio)"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:variable name="zzz_specialInstruction" select="count(//CustomField[@name = 'Text3']/StringValue)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$zzz_specialInstruction &gt; 0">
          <xsl:element name="specialInstruction">
            <xsl:attribute name="code">ZZZ</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="text">
              <xsl:value-of select="//CustomField[@name = 'Text3']/StringValue"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the next node don´t appear in my XML generate:

```
<xsl:variable name="zzz_specialInstruction" select="count(//CustomField[@name = 'Text3']/StringValue)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$zzz_specialInstruction &gt; 0">
      <xsl:element name="specialInstruction">
        <xsl:attribute name="code">ZZZ</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="text">
          <xsl:value-of select="//CustomField[@name = 'Text3']/StringValue"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
```

My problem is that, when i compile the code of my XSLT, it´s node doesn´t appears. My dude is why doesn´t appear this node in my XML file.???

Comment: We'll probably need some input XML. But generally... if you're asking why a xsl:value doesn't show up in your produced XML it's because it's an XSL variable, not an output template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:variable` elements assign a value to the given name of the variable created. Just like in the following python code, `x = 3*3`, the number won't print without a print statement like so:

```
x = 3*3
print x
# Displays 9 on the screen.
```

Likewise, in XSLT, this:

```
<xsl:variable name="x" select="3*3" />
```

does nothing. The only way to have this produced in the output XML file is to execute a command which will render it in the output, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="x" select="3*3" />
<xsl:element name="x">
    <xsl:value select="$x"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Which will produce:

```
<x>9</x>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you could write this much more readably as:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Addenda>
      <requestForPayment
           type="SimpleInvoiceType"
           contentVersion="1.3.1"
           documentStructureVersion="AMC7.1"
           documentStatus="ORIGINAL"
           DeliveryDate="{substring(translate(//DocDate, ' ', ''),1,10)}">
        <requestForPaymentIdentification>
          <entityType>
            <xsl:call-template name="Tpos_Documento"/>
          </entityType>
          <uniqueCreatorIdentification>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(//Serial/Name,//Serial/Folio)"/>
          </uniqueCreatorIdentification>
        </requestForPaymentIdentification >
        <xsl:variable name="zzz_specialInstruction" 
                      select="count(//CustomField[@name = 'Text3']/StringValue)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$zzz_specialInstruction &gt; 0">
          <specialInstruction code="ZZZ">
            <text>
              <xsl:value-of select="//CustomField[@name = 'Text3']/StringValue"/>
            </text>
          </specialInstruction >
        </xsl:if>
   ...
  </xsl:template>
```